# Why does my Event Receiver (sandboxed) not work on Sharepoint Online, but works perfect on premise

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receivers

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace Change_Title_Event.Change_Title
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List Item Events
    /// </summary>
    public class Change_Title : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// An item is being added.
       /// </summary>
       public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           properties.AfterProperties["Title"] = "Kevin: Changed by event receiver at" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
           base.ItemAdding(properties);
       }


    }
}
```

Where simple example, which works **perfect** on my local Sharepoint 2010. **It is sandboxed.**

But when I package this solution, it do not work on Sharepoint Online. I does not give any Errors either.

I think I am doing something wrong, something simple, but I can't simply find anything on Google about it.

Here is another who asks on the MSDN forum, but gets a very wierd reply, that I do not understand.
http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/153/t/48868.aspx

Comment: Microsoft have also an example here, but that do not work either. I am using it with a annoncement list, but it do not add anything to the body.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Online-Creating-cd88a09c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have to activate two times.

Both in the solution page and the you have to go to the Feature page and activate the feature.

// I was confused because normally you only have to activate once.

Comment: In my case it is activated in both places, and the receiver is still not working on online (on premises works fine, though).

Comment: Sandbox solution is activated once.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have to activate two times.

Both in the solution page and the you have to go to the Feature page and activate the feature.

check this post:
[Why does my Event Receiver (sandboxed) not work on Sharepoint Online, but works perfect on premise](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41145/why-does-my-event-receiver-sandboxed-not-work-on-sharepoint-online-but-works)

http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/60731.aspx

Comment: I have activated the feature correctly.  It is activated on the solution gallery AND the Site Feature Activation.

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox solution should be activated first.

Then there must be one of many Features part of the solution referencing objects, events, etc. contained in the solution. Activating this feature will deliver all items as specified in it.

Answer (score -1):

Sandbox solutions has been deprecated using custom code. Please check the below link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions.aspx

May be that is reason your event receiver is not working.