# ItemUpdated event receiver not trigger when item update from workflow in sandbox solution

Tags: workflow, document-library, office-365, event-receivers, sandbox-solution

Itemupdated Event Receiver not triggered when item update from workflow

I have created workflow on document library which simply update single column. And i have also create **ItemUpdated** event receiver which change permission on document.

But itemUpdated event not trigger from workflow. But when i update item manually then event receiver triggered.

I have use **Update Item** in workflow to trigger Itemupdated event but still event receiver not trigger. But upon manually updation of item event receiver trigger.

Is there any issue or i forget any step in process. Or is it not supported in office 365?

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41145/why-does-my-event-receiver-sandboxed-not-work-on-sharepoint-online-but-works) is a bit similar as yours, which says :

> It is because you have to activate two times.
>
> Both in the solution page and the you have to go to the Feature page
> and activate the feature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Vishwas. I have activated both time. And my event receiver works when i change any item manually. It not works only when item updated from workflow.